# Integrating skype in own website JDK

Tags: javascript, skype

I am trying to integrate skype within my website. Features I want to use in my websites are:

1. Sign-in and sign-out
2. Video or Audio calling
3. Chatting

Also I want to store chat messages in my local database so I can have track of conversation for future use. So, My questions are:

> 1. Is it possible to integrate skype in website?
> 2. If yes, How can we integrate it?
> 3. Is it necessary to have desktop application installed for web application?

My priority is Javascript SDK but I am also flexible with any other programming integration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you searched WEB? https://www.google.com/search?q=skype+api&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=O4EhWI3DDuyv8wfh5YEI

Comment: Yes, But I don't found microsoft's documentation very helpful.

Comment: You can do this with the skype web sdk: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/skypewebsdk . When using the Conversation Control you get the full skype look 'n feel experience. You dont need a desktop client. But its just for Skype for business